# Utf-8 codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 185: invalid start byte

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, pyinstaller

Is there  anyone else getting this error when running pyinstaller?

```
Utf-8 codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 185: invalid start byte
```

I saved my python file with a notepad++ in utf-8 without bom but that hasnt helped. Pyinstaller was working fine earlier and just suddenly I began getting this error. Is anyone experiencing the same issue?
Regards,

Comment: I think what you're having is utf-16 format.

Comment: No, i even converted my python file already in utf-8 to utf-8, and I still get the same results

Comment: Your question seems to be  too broad and is likely to be 
[put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please [edit] it and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit late to the party, but I was having this exact issue. you can use open as 'rb' so that it won't try to convert the text to ANSI. I did mine like this:

```
with open(path_to_file,'rb') as f:
contents = f.read()
contents = contents.rstrip("\n").decode("utf-16")   
contents = contents.split("\r\n")
```

The contents.split is just for formatting. when you decode the data within the file, it'll keep all the /r/n (if in windows) or /n (if in linux)

hope this helps!